# How to use column names in PHP PDO without binding columns

Tags: php, pdo

Is there a method to directly use the name of the column when outputting data without binding columns when using php pdo and mySql, instead of using `$row[‘columnName’]`.

**Eg: My current method**

```
$sql = "select id, name, address, country from members where country = :country";
$stmt=$conn->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute(array(':country' => $country));
while( $row = $stmt->fetch() ) { //I can forgo the while loop.
    echo $row[‘name’]; //Can I use $name here?
    echo $row[‘address’];
    echo $row[‘country’];
}
```

Instead of using `$row[‘colName’]`, is it possible to somehow use `$colName` itself? I know `ezSql` does it this way, but I’m not using `ezSql` since it does not support prepared statements. How can this be done? Maybe using `for each`? Is it possible?

I know I can bind columns, but I'm trying to avoid that too. Keep code at a minimum.

Comment: Please don't delete your previous questions only to ask the same thing again

Comment: @Ben The answer may very well lie in [this comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19173673/how-to-use-column-names-in-php-pdo-without-binding-columns#comment28366027_19173673)

Comment: I just love magic fancy quotes, they're just Oh so fancy... and *destructive.*

Comment: Downvote because: 1. Access to array members has absolutely nothing to do with PDO. 2. The question itself is a mere whim. Keeping your data in array is cleaner and preferable. 3. It seems the OP have no idea on templates, *which* should be his first and foremost concern.

Comment: @YourCommonSense Fair enough, though I'm usually pro-education and against punishment..

Comment: @Ben downvote is not a "punishment". Yet the OP indeed deserved one, for deleting his other question and asking it again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you **really** don't want to bind columns or use array references or object properties and don't mind polluting the current variable scope, try this ugly hack

```
while( $row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) ) {
    extract($row);
    echo $name;
    // etc
}
```

As mentioned in my answer on your [previous, duplicate question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19173207/283366), `PDOStatement::bindColumn` would be preferable. I really don't know what you're trying to achieve by *"keeping code to a minimum"* other than prove yourself unprofessional.

Comment: No, I think it is. It both answers the question and clearly outlines why it's a bad idea. Great answer actually :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code:

```
extract($row);
```

and then you have:

`$name`, `$address`, etc.