# Storing common code in a separate file

Tags: php

I'm trying to keep long lists of `bindColumn` statements and other code in `separate` files and use them where it's needed instead of having them pollute the main code. I've created a file called stock.php, and put all the `bindColumn` statements in them, and included them on each page. Somehow, I don't seem to be getting this right, and keep ending up with lots of errors.

How can I do something like this?

```
select x, y, z, a, b, c from table;
$stmt->execute($array);
//Instead of writing all those bindColumn statements here after the select, 
//I'd like to keep them in a seperate file and include them here. How?


//In a seperate file
function bindCols(){
    $x = '$stmt->bindColumn('x',$x);';
    $x = '$stmt->bindColumn('y',$y);';
    $x = '$stmt->bindColumn('z',$z);';
    $x = '$stmt->bindColumn('a',$a);';
    $x = '$stmt->bindColumn('b',$b);';
    $x = '$stmt->bindColumn('c',$c);';
    $x = '$stmt->bindColumn('d',$d);';

    return $x;
}
```

Comment: Try passing `$stmt` into your function as a parameter?

Comment: I have no idea what you're trying to do.... you're just re-assigning values to `$x` and `'$stmt->bindColumn('d',$d);';` doesn't even use proper string concatenation (or you need to use double quotes on the outside - I'm not sure what your goal is) and I'm not sure where the variables a, b, c, d... are coming from in that function. And you don't have anything grabbing the return value from `bindCols()` and as far as I can see, `$stmt` doesn't even exist in that function unless you plan on doing eval or something with the return value?

Comment: [see examples on how to bind parameters](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php)... i am linking pdo because that is what you seem to be using.

Comment: I'm trying to keep these bindColumn statements separately and then output them where they are needed.

Comment: what do you mean exactly... can you write some pseudo code on the steps you want to take?  what do you mean "output them where they are needed"?

Comment: `eval` used in this situation would not be dangerous I guess. I'm not accepting user input here...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With more information, I can make this example more complete for you...

```
   $params['calories'] = 150;
   $params['colour'] = 'red';


   $stmt = $dbh->prepare('SELECT name, colour, calories
                          FROM fruit
                          WHERE calories < :calories AND colour = :colour'); 

   bindColumns($stmt,$params); 

   $stmt->execute();

   function bindColumns(&$stmt, $params)
   {
      foreach($params as $key => $value)
      {
         $stmt->bindValue(":$key", $value); 
      } 
   }
```

Quick Note:
* [bindParam()](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php) needs to take its values by reference
* [bindValue()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindvalue.php) does not

---

okay... so binding after:

```
   $params = array('name','color','calories');

   $stmt = $dbh->prepare('SELECT name, color, calories FROM fruit');  

   $stmt->execute();   

   foreach($params as $index => $name) {  
      $stmt->bindColumn("$name", $$name);  
   }   

   while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_BOUND)) {
      print $name . "\t" . $color . "\t\t" . $calories . "<br/>"; 
   }
```

This uses something called a [variable variable](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php) to make dynamic variable names (`$$name`)... like the `extract()` function almost.  The thing is... if I put the `foreach($params...` into its own function, they are lost in the scope of that function.  The only alternative would be to make them an array and either pass it in by reference or return it.  If you did that, you would use `print $return_params['name']` or something.

```
   $stmt = $dbh->prepare('SELECT name, color, calories FROM fruit');  

   $success = $stmt->execute();   

   $return = bindColumnsAfterSelect($stmt, $params); 

   while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_BOUND)) {
      print $return['name'] . "\t" . $return['color'] . "\t\t" . $return['calories'] . "<br/>"; 
   }


   function bindColumnsAfterSelect(&$stmt, $params)
   {     
      $return = array(); 

      foreach($params as $index => $name) {  
         $stmt->bindColumn("$name", $return[$name]);  
      }  

      return $return; 
   }
```

And... you don't need to have everything named the same... you can do:

```
   $params = array('name'=>'fruit_name','color'=>'fruit_color','calories'=>'fruit_calories');
```

then...

```
   foreach($params as $table_name => $variable_name) {  
       $stmt->bindColumn("$table_name", $$variable_name);  
   }
```

Annnnnnd... I don't really use PDO so I'm not sure what you're doing exactly but [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19173713/623952) might be an easier alternative for you?  Dunno.  Here's a code sample from that page:

```
while( $row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) ) {
    extract($row);
    echo $name;
    // etc
}
```

---

**edit, again:** this is what you want.... but I really, really, *really* would not do it this way.

```
   $stmt = $dbh->prepare('SELECT name, color, calories FROM fruit');  

   $success = $stmt->execute();   

   $return = bindColumnsAfterSelect(); 

   eval($return);  // this is a bad function to use like this.  
                   // it does what you want but... it's just not right
                   // it's extremely powerful and shouldn't be used
                   // for things like this... 

   while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_BOUND)) {
      print $name . "\t" . $color . "\t\t" . $calories . "<br/>"; 
   }

   function bindColumnsAfterSelect()
   {     
      $x  = '$stmt->bindColumn("name", $name);';
      $x .= '$stmt->bindColumn("color", $color);';
      $x .= '$stmt->bindColumn("calories", $calories);'; 

      return $x; 
   }
```

Comment: I'm not trying to `bindParam()` or `bindValue()`, I'm trying to `bindColumns` after a select. My bad I left the select in the question.

Comment: My problem is keeping code in a seperate file and then using it as part of a script

Comment: does that make sense?  is it along the lines of what you're looking for?

Comment: I'm trying it out. My original idea was to simply include those bindColunm statements where they were needed.

Comment: Okay, well... you were just reassigning `$x` to different values.  If you properly concatenated the string together and escaped things (`$` and `'`) correctly, technically you could pass it back and use [eval()](http://us1.php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php) to execute the string as a PHP code... but eval() should only be used when absolutely necessary.  It's not a good idea.

Comment: I did correct that code, but still can't get it right. Maybe I'll stick to leaving them in there itself.